# Struggling to get an amplified sine wave over a small inductor at low frequencies

Tags: audio, inductor, passive-networks, resonance, power-amplifier

I am building a power amplifier circuit to amplify a sine wave over an inductor from a function generator. However because the inductor is small and i'm running at a low frequency I am getting concerning signals across it: 
[image: Signal across inductor]

I have tried using a push pull amplifier but the signal is not much better:
[image: Push pull amplifier output]

I figured it was because of the reactance of the inductor that is causing this because when I increase the inductance or frequency I get an expected sine wave. So I created a parallel RLC circuit with the inductor and that brings me a sine wave however now I am getting little voltage amplification but if I remove the resistor then I get a current far too high.
[image: RLC circuit fixish]

I am wondering if anyone can think of a better fix because I am now getting no voltage gain and the inductor is already an auxiliary winding to drive a resonance circuit so I would like to not try and deal with another RLC circuit.

The signal across the inductor with a lower gain factor and smaller input signal:
[image: Smaller signal output]

Comment: your transistor models do not permit huge currents to be generated. What is your required inductor current, at what frequency? what is the inductor internal series resistance?

Comment: I'm aiming for an inductor current of around 1A rms but it doesn't have to be exact, just enough to drive the main winding, I want the frequency at 50Hz and according to the LCR meter the internal resistance is 3ohms.

Comment: [The 2N3904](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N3903-D.PDF) is only rated for 200mA, so you'll not be getting the required current through your push-pull circuit.

Comment: [Your OPA548](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/opa548) on the other hand **can** handle the required current.

Comment: @JRE Thank you, i'll ensure I drive the inductor straight from the op-amp, do you have any suggestions on how to fix the signal across the inductor?

Comment: I was just looking at the datasheet for the OPA548.  It looks like you have current limiting set for about 1.6A.  That's R4.  If you connect the current limit pin straight to -V, does it get better?  That would be full current (5A.)

Comment: The input voltage is 8.48V peak to peak with a 10 times amplification factor? You expect 84.8V peak to peak at the output with +- 15V power supply? The amp is working in nonlinear area so that"s why you don't get the expected result. Try a ten times lower input voltage with the original design and show your findings again.

Comment: I agree with @Dorian.  Lower the gain, or use a lower input signal.

Comment: @Dorian I was only using such a large resistance at R2 to see if I could drive a high voltage into the RLC circuit, the value I actually use is 1Kohm which gives me a gain of 2, sorry I should have made that more clear. However, unfortunately the problem still persists regardless of the value of the gain factor.

Comment: @JRE No difference has been made and 5A would be too much for the inductor so I have to keep it limited.

Comment: Then please show the graphs using realistic values.

Comment: @Dorian Have just made an edit showing the changes.

Comment: The issue is that C5 and L1 making a resonant circuit at 50Hz and the load impedance tends to zero. Try a 10000uF for C5 to avoid the resonance.